# Basis given the rank of A is equal to n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with columns $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_n$. If $\operatorname{rank} (A) = n$, show that $\{ A^T C_1,\dots,A^T C_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm really confused about how I should do this. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $A$ is an $m$x$n$ matrix instead of $S$?

Comment: Fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: what are the properties of a basis in general?

**Edit: some more hints**

You need to show two things namely:

- Linear independence
- That they span $\mathbb{R^n}$

What do you know of the rank of $A^T$ given what you know of that of $A$? How could you represent $\{ A^T C_1,\dots,A^T C_n\}$ in a different way?

---

Alright, to be more specific:
$\{ A^T C_1,\dots,A^T C_n\}$ are the columns of $A^TA$. The rank of $rank(A^TA)=rank(A)=n$ By definition of the rank, these columns are all linearly independent and together span $\mathbb{R^n}$. Hence, they form a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to start

Comment: Rank A transpose is equal to n and because rank A equals n the rows of a span $\mathbb{R}and the columns   are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @Ryan You are getting closer but you still miss out on a few things. I will edit my post to elaborate some more.